# How can I repeat a POST request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some error-handling code that sometimes needs to do some stuff and then re-try the current request. This works fine when it's a GET request, but not otherwise. In other words, I can't `redirect_to request.path` when `request.post?` is true.

Is there some way I can take the current request object, be it GET, POST, PATCH, or whatever, and just restart it?

Comment: Is your error-handling code located on backend or on frontend? Do you want to retry the whole HTTP request flow or you're only concerned with a controller action logic?

Comment: Redirect is meant for GET requests, what you want is an HTTP library and rebuild the POST request using all the information you have. Typhoeus is a popular choice.

Comment: @NicNilov - it's on the backend. My preference would be to just start from the top of the stack and do the whole request over, but I think it would suffice here to start over in the controller action. In fact, maybe it's as simple as that -- just figuring out the current controller action and calling it explicitly? (Presuming the error is fixed so that we don't go into an infinite loop.)

Comment: Rails way is when an error happens while processing `create` or `update` action (which are called to handle `POST` and `PUT` requests) to render the originating form's action, `new` or `update`, respectively, and display errors. User can then fix input and resubmit. This way the operation doesn't have to involve a complete roundtrip to user's browser. To tell more we need to see your code, I should've asked you to add that from the start.

Comment: Thanks @NicNilov - this is a bit of an odd case. I'm kludging together a workaround for some buggy backend third-party code I'm using until I can figure out what's wrong with it. So the error is not in the user data, it's on my end. I just need to fix something in the db and then start over. The code is far too ugly to see the light of day here :)